# Am I able to transfer records (Answers/Questions/Others) on Stack Overflow from one email to another?

Tags: discussion, email

Since my current Stack Overflow is based on a non-permanent email, all information/data stored by this email account will be eventually deleted.

So can I transfer email accounts on this platform while keeping all of my records?

I have looked at my account settings, but there are no showings for account transfer.

Comment: Can't you just update the address in the settings for the existing account?

Comment: Your answer helps. Thank you.